# Dell PowerEdge 1950 Drive Bay not showing in SAS Configuration Utility

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, sas

We have a Dell PowerEdge 1950 in RAID 1.  Recently, the drive in Bay 0 began rapidly blinking green (I'm guessing twice per second, indicating "identifying drive").

When I open the SAS Configuration Utility and look at the SAS topology, it only shows Bay 1--Bay 0 doesn't even show up.  When I replace the drive with a new one (we had to swap out the drive in Bay 1 last month with the exact model/firmware, so I know these new drives are proper), Bay 0 still does not show up.  Refresh does nothing.  Do we have a problem with the SAS controller?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MDMarra is right without logs we are a little bit blind, so, or you restart the server with a OMSA LiveDVD/CD or you can, if you want, install OMSA in ESXi, you can find info how to install it in this link:
http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/f/4469/p/19428204/20016620.aspx#20016620

OMSA LIveDVD -> http://linux.dell.com/files/openmanage-contributions/omsa-71-live/OMSA71-CentOS6-x86_64-LiveDVD.iso

But in general you have to think in a problem in the SAS chain, controller, backplane and cable

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the controller or the backplane.

You can dump the PERC logs using OpenManage. That should give you some indication of what's going on. If you can't decipher it, you should call Dell support.

Comment: We are running ESXi 5.x _without_ vCenter, so I don't think OpenManage will work in this environment.  There are no errors indicated on the ticker panel on the server either.  Anything else I can do short of calling Dell?

Comment: If you don't have visibility into the hardware, then I don't know how you can diagnose anything... You can probably get some info from the DRAC. Have you looked there, or did you get a configuration without a DRAC as well?